# image texture stretched

Tags: texturing, image

please anyone can help me.
as shown at the attached picture the left part is the modeled bottle, when i applied the image texture, it's stretched as you see, but what i need it to be as the flat design on the right part.
please how can i fix this issue .

thanks in advance,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ever tried to resize/re-adjust the unwrapped mesh over the image in the uv-editor?
Works best when watching the render preview simultaneously.
Best regards,
Andal